# How do I lock an entire SQLite connection (locked read + locked write)?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, python-multithreading

I have an sqlite3 db that is being accessed concurrently. I have `ClientA` that reads the state of some table (Column1 has rows **A**, **B**, **C**) and needs to update the table with new letters of the alphabet. If `ClientB` reads the state of the table before `ClientA` updates the table (say with the new letter **D**), then it's possible that both clients could (and in my case *do*) write **D** to the table - such that Column1 becomes **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **D**. But I need to ensure Column1 only has unique letters!

How do I lock the db connection so that its read AND write operations get exclusive access so that Column1 doesn't accidentally change states between some other read-write cycle?

It's hard to find anything about "locking a sqlite read" online because everyone seems more interested in unlocking the db. The following doesn't seem to give `con`'s read operations [exclusive access](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level)

```
con = sqlite3.connect(db, isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE', timeout=10)
```

Related:

- [File locking - read then write whilst locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914102/file-locking-read-then-write-whilst-locked)
- [How perform SQLite query with a data reader without locking database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367118/how-perform-sqlite-query-with-a-data-reader-without-locking-database?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting the isolation level is not enough. You must also place your exclusive statements in transaction:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(db, isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE', timeout=10)
con.execute('BEGIN EXCLUSIVE')
# Exclusive access here; no other transaction can access the database.
# 1. Check for presence of letter
# 2. Add the letter if it doesn't exist
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: This is useful though I'm thinking my general approach to this beast is bad (for instance, now my entire script fails the moment I get a single db lock). If you've got time I'd appreciate you checking out [the rest of the story here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294643/how-to-avoid-race-write-conditions-while-incrementing-a-count-in-sqlite)