# Profile Millions of Text Files In Parallel Using An Sqlite Counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, multiprocessing

A mountain of text files (of types A, B and C) is sitting on my chest, slowly, coldly refusing me desperately needed air. Over the years each type spec has had *enhancements* such that yesterday's typeA file has many more properties than last year's typeA. To build a parser that can handle the decade's long evolution of these file types it makes sense to inspect all 14 million of them iteratively, calmly, but before dying beneath their crushing weight.

I built a running counter such that every time I see properties (familiar or not) I add 1 to its tally. The `sqlite` tally board looks like this:

[image]

In the special event I see an unfamiliar property I add them to the tally. On a typeA file that looks like:

[image]

I've got this system down! But it's slow @ 3M files/36 hours in one process. Originally I was using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/3491991) to pass `sqlite` a list of properties needing increment.

```
placeholder= '?' # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for dummy_var in properties)
sql = """UPDATE tally_board
SET %s = %s + 1
WHERE property IN (%s)""" %(type_name, type_name, placeholders)
cursor.execute(sql, properties)
```

I learned that's a bad idea because

1. `sqlite` string search is much slower than indexed search
2. several hundreds of properties (some 160 characters long) make for **really** long sql queries
3. using `%s` instead of `?` is bad security practice... (not a concern ATM)

A "fix" was to maintain a script side `property`-`rowid` hash of the tally used in this loop:

1. Read file for `new_properties`
2. Read `tally_board` for `rowid`, `property`
3. Generate script side `client_hash` from 2's read
4. Write rows to `tally_board` for every `new_property` not in `property` (nothing incremented yet). Update `client_hash` with new properties
5. Lookup `rowid` for every row in `new_properties` using the `client_hash`
6. Write increment to every `rowid` (now a proxy for `property`) to `tally_board`

Step 6. looks like

```
sql = """UPDATE tally_board
SET %s = %s + 1
WHERE rowid IN %s""" %(type_name, type_name, tuple(target_rows))
cur.execute
```

The problem with this is

- **It's still slow!**
- It manifests a race condition in parallel processing that introduces duplicates in the `property` column whenever threadA starts step 2 right before threadB completes step 6.

A solution to the race condition is to give steps 2-6 an exclusive lock on the db <s>though it doesn't look like reads can get those</s> [Lock A Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40294507/3491991).

Another attempt [uses a genuine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/3491991) `UPSERT` to increment preexisting `property` rows AND insert (and increment) new `property` rows in one fell swoop.

There may be luck in [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463024/3491991) but I'm unsure how to rewrite it to increment the tally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sped things up immensely:

- Wrote less often to `SQLite`. Holding most of my intermediate results in memory then updating the DB with them every 50k files resulted in about a third of the execution time (35 hours to 11.5 hours)
- Moving data onto my PC (for some reason my USB3.0 port was transferring data well below USB2.0 rates). This resulted in about a fifth of the execution time (11.5 hours to 2.5 hours).

Answer (score 1):

How about a change of table schema? Instead of a column per type, have a type column. Then you have unique rows identified by property and type, like this:

```
|rowid|prop    |type |count|
============================
|1    |prop_foo|typeA|215  |
|2    |prop_foo|typeB|456  |
```

This means you can enter a transaction for each and every property of each and every file separately and let `sqlite` worry about races. So for each property you encounter, immediately issue a complete transaction that computes the next total and upserts the record identified by the property name and file type.

Comment: Does that have the same effect as keeping my current schema but individually (not batch) updating the table as you suggest?

Comment: Well with your current schema you inherently create race conditions between updates arising from unrelated file types. Since a file has (presumably) only a single file type, this means you avoid a whole set of race conditions by keying your records based on file type. However you could define a view that is recomputed periodically (possibly triggered via an explicit command after a batch import of a fresh fileset) which aggregates the results in your old format for convenience.

Comment: In turn, each race condition that you avoid implies one more case in which transactions execute in the happy/fast path, instead of incurring potentially costly locking/rollbacks.

Comment: Also, having a single `type` column is easier to scale than having N type specific columns. After all, each new  file type you didn't foresee is now just another value instead of an expensive schema update.

Comment: It turns out writing to the db _more often_ slows things down even more. Recipe: when using sqlite + multiprocessing, write to sqlite as infrequently as possible. Offloading most of what I'd been trying to do in sqlite onto memory cut time down 60%.